# How to use EnumValueOptions in protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use the custom options feature in protobuf. I'm not sure if I'm creating the custom option incorrectly, or if I'm trying to retrieve the option incorrectly.

Here's my proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package common;

message Foo {
    EventType event_type = 1;
}

enum AuditEventType {
    AuditEventDefault = 0;
    AuditEventError = 1;
    AuditEventInfo = 2;
}

enum EventType { 
    Undefined = 0;
    AuditSourceType.Pearl)]
    Lead = 1 [(audit_event_type) = AuditEventInfo];
}

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    AuditEventType audit_event_type = 50000;
}
```

So in my code, how would I get the the `audit_event_type` from the `event_type` field on `Foo`?

I see examples like such:

```
func TestExtension(t *testing.T) {
    foo := &Foo{
        EventType: EventType_Lead,
    }

    _, md := descriptor.ForMessage(foo)

    auditEvent, err := proto.GetExtension(md.Options, E_AuditEventType)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("error:", err)
    }
    t.Log(auditEvent)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
error: proto: nil *descriptor.MessageOptions is not extendable
```